# DateDiff is not showing up

Tags: vb.net, datediff

I've got a very simple program:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim birthDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
        Dim dateDifference As DateTime = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTime.Now, birthDate)
        Console.WriteLine(dateDifference.ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Trying to use `DateDiff` gives me the error "DateDiff is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level." Everything I have looked at says that `DateDiff` should be in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace. I've imported that namespace as you can see. I even added a reference to it in the Solution Explorer. Very frustrating, will someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Dim dateDifference As Decimal is wrong. Should declare it as Timespan

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Just changed it to a TimeSpan and that does not work still.

Comment: Birthdate should be Datetime type

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli doesn't .Month return an integer though? It seems quite a bit needs changing

Comment: You might think of using the .NET Substract class method instead of the old VB Datediff.

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file. VS will answer all your questions.

Comment: Month is Month. Integer is integer. The fact that months can be enumerated is no shortcut.

Comment: Corrected my program to now have `Option Strict On` but I'm still getting the previously listed error.

Comment: You might be importing Microsoft.VisualBasic but it's possible it's not in your references. Personally, if it's a new project, I wouldn't use it and use the Substract method of the DateTime.

Comment: Something is already wonky when you need Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.  Project > Properties > References tab, the "Imported Namespaces" lists the namespaces that don't require an explicit Imports statement in source.  But you probably forgot to tell us that you are trying to create a .NETCore or .NETStandard project.  These legacy functions needed to be retired some day.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Strict On
Imports System
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim birthDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
        Dim dateDifference As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTime.Now, birthDate)
        Console.WriteLine(dateDifference.ToString)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

This works.

Comment: The correct syntax is DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTime.Now, birthDate) and not DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTime.Now - birthDate)

Comment: Put that information in your post, not in your comments.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me. Did you have to do something special to import the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace? I also right clicked on my solution name>add>reference and added a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll. I'm stumped.

Comment: The class is DateAndTime, so try full name qualification with DateAndtime.DateDiff, although this is odd...

Answer (score 1):

You had two problems in your code

1. DateDiff returns a long. You have a DateTime being assigned.
2. You had a DateTime.Now-birthDate instead of a DateTime.Now, birthDate in your call

```vb
Sub Main(args As String())
  Dim birthDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
  Dim dateDifference As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, DateTime.Now, birthDate)
  Console.WriteLine(dateDifference.ToString)
  Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: A Long! How old do you think I am? :-)